# Print the content in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, printing

I am trying to print the content in the iframe. My iframe source is powerbi report URL.

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("printpage").contentWindow.print();
}
</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>


<iframe id="printpage" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

When I am trying to print the report,I get access denied error on contentWindow.print() line. Please let me know how can I get over this problem.

Comment: in your code the LAST line you have too many Speech marks in src parameter

Comment: Corrected. Thank you for pointing out. It is not my problem though.

Comment: Did you check for cross request origin?

Comment: <iframe id="printpage" designMode=on src="http://powerbiserver/ReportsPBI/powerbi/Graph"></iframe>                                  try designMode=on

Comment: Denny, designMode=on didn't help.. The powerbi server is in the same domain as the requesting web page. Is there any other way to make this work?